# Surface doesn't have a colorkey

Tags: sdl-2

I coming back on a project writen few months ago with SDL 2.0.5 AFAIR and I now update it to the last available version.

And when my application calls `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface )`, `SDL_GetError()` complains with `Surface doesn't have a colorkey` message.

I'm almost sure this error is new but I cannot figure out why.

My code is:

```
SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load( imgName );
SDL_ClearError();
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surface );
if (strlen(SDL_GetError()) > 0)
{
    LOG_mes(WID_ERR_NO_TEXTURE, SDL_GetError());
}
```

If you could help me please and maybe point me to the SDL2_image doc because informations found [here](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) don't really help me as the links seem broken.

Comment: What makes you think there is an error? Is `texture` a NULL? If not, there is no reason to look at `SDL_GetError`, it may contain anything (SDL sometimes raises error message on minor non-critical things).

Comment: @keltar, I don't really agree if I call `SDL_CleaError()` then get something in `SDL_GetError()` after calling a SDL function, it means that one generated an error maybe minor, but something went wrong. I could rely on the fact that the return is not null but I'm sure I didn't get it before so maybe minor error in 2.0.8, maybe severe in 2.0.9, how to know? I would prefer to solve it...

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError `The message is only applicable when an SDL function has signaled an error. You must check the return values of SDL function calls to determine when to appropriately call SDL_GetError().`. Due to SDL internals error message may be set but if it is handled in SDL itself and it gives you no reason to look at error message - it's fine. E.g. `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` pretty much always sets error message on X11, which is completely fine.

Comment: To clarify - it is not about severity of error, function in question uses other SDL functions, some of which may raise error message, but higher level funciton handles it gracefully and produces desired result; no indication of error is returned so any message that may be set have no meaning anymore (it had when it was raised - but it isn't you who called error-raising function, and this error is already handled). Clearing errors on each operation would be counterproductive and bad for performance, so SDL don't do that. So it isn't a hint or warning, you literally shouldn't check err message.

Comment: @keltar. Ok I understand, thanks a lot.